# Generating Random Numbers Until Some Condition Is Met

Tags: r, loops

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to learn more about WHILE LOOPS and thought of the following problem to implement them in:

- Step 1: Keep generating 3 random numbers until the sum of these 3 numbers is > 150
- Step 2: Save the results from Step 1 and the number of times you had to generate these numbers until the condition was met
- Step 3 : Repeat Step 1 - Step 2 for 100 turns

I tried to do this like this:

```
num_1_i = num_2_i = num_3_i = 0

list_results <- list()

for (i in 1:100)

{

while (num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150) {


turn_i = i
num_1_i = runif(1,0,100)
num_2_i = runif(1,0,100)
num_3_i = runif(1,0,100)
break
}

inter_results_i <- data.frame(turn_i, num_1_i, num_2_i, num_3_i)

list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
   
}
```

This is producing the same numbers every time:

```
[[98]]
  turn_i  num_1_i num_2_i  num_3_i
1      1 87.67886 32.7703 52.72885

[[99]]
  turn_i  num_1_i num_2_i  num_3_i
1      1 87.67886 32.7703 52.72885

[[100]]
  turn_i  num_1_i num_2_i  num_3_i
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?**

Thanks!

Note: Alternate Method I tried - still doesn't work:

```
list_results <- list()

for (i in 100) {
  repeat {
   

turn_i = i
num_1_i = runif(1,0,100)
num_2_i = runif(1,0,100)
num_3_i = runif(1,0,100)

    if(num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150) break
  }
  results_tmp <- data.frame(turn = i, num_1 = num_1_i, num_2 = num_2_i, num_3 = num_3_i)
  
  list_results[[i]] <- results_tmp
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt using `while` is on track, just need one slight modification: **putting the line** `num_1_i = num_2_i = num_3_i = 0` **inside the for-loop, outside the while-loop**

```
for (i in 1:100){
  num_1_i = num_2_i = num_3_i = 0
  
  while(num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150){
    num_1_i = runif(1,0,100)
    num_2_i = runif(1,0,100)
    num_3_i = runif(1,0,100)
  }
  
  inter_results_i <- data.frame(i, num_1_i, num_2_i, num_3_i)
  list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
}
```

What's happening is that during `i = 1`, you've generated 3 numbers that satisfy the condition, but they were never reset to zero. So every subsequent iteration of `for` it is immediately skipping the `while`.

Comment: @ jkuo_ut : thank you! this seems to have worked!

Answer (score 2):

***Lets check your code:***

```
while (num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150) {
  turn_i = i
  num_1_i = runif(1,0,100)
  num_2_i = runif(1,0,100)
  num_3_i = runif(1,0,100)
  break >>>> LOOK AT HERE! YOUR LOOP WILL WORK ONLY ONE TIME AND BREAKS HERE
}
```

**And there is some difference between WHILE and REPEAT loops:**

In **WHILE** loops the criteria(s) is/are checked in the begining of the loop, and if it returns TRUE, code block will run, in this situation maybe your code is not working fine! But in **REPEAT** loops, code block ***will run at least one time***! look at here:

```
repeat{
  num_1_i = runif(1,0,100)
  num_2_i = runif(1,0,100)
  num_3_i = runif(1,0,100)
  if(num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150){
    break
  }
}
```

In my opinion, you should use **REPEAT** in this case.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is because after finding the first combination that exceeds 150 you don't reset the numbers back to 0. So it never enters the `while` loop again and the same numbers are stored 100 times.

Simply move the first line of setting numbers to 0 into the for loop:

```
list_results <- list()

for (i in 1:100)

{
num_1_i = num_2_i = num_3_i = 0

while (num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i < 150) {

turn_i = i
num_1_i = runif(1,0,100)
num_2_i = runif(1,0,100)
num_3_i = runif(1,0,100)
break
}

inter_results_i <- data.frame(turn_i, num_1_i, num_2_i, num_3_i)

list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
   
}
```

Comment: @ Viggnah: thank you for your answer! When I try " while (num_1_i + num_2_i + num_3_i > 200) " - I get a list of all 0's. Shouldn't the code keep producing random numbers until they exceed the specified threshold? thank you so much!

Comment: Greater than 200 or less than 200? Because `0+0+0>200` fails and doesn't enter while loop at all. So stores 0 repeatedly!

Comment: Is there any way to fix this without specifically initializing num_1, num_2, num_3? thank you so much!

Comment: Is it because you want to get greater than 200 working? For the greater than case simply set `num_1_i = num_2_i = num_3_i = 200` instead of `0`. Then it will go into while loop and repeat until it finds numbers that are going to be less than 200.